# 403 forbidden error while doing POST request in GoLang

Tags: rest, go, http-post

```
//Send put request with given params
func SendPostRequest(url string, param map[string]interface{}, authToken string) string{

//to disable security check
http.DefaultTransport.(*http.Transport).TLSClientConfig = &tls.Config{InsecureSkipVerify: true}
//Parse to json
jsonValue, _ := json.Marshal(param)
req, err := http.NewRequest("POST", url, bytes.NewBuffer(jsonValue))
req.Header.Add("Content-Type", "application/json")
req.Header.Add("AuthToken", authToken)


client := &http.Client{}
resp, err := client.Do(req)
}
```

Here is the JSON file

```
{"credentials":{"display_name":"win10Test","is_default":"","password":"","username":""},
"defaultschedule":true,"host_info":{"ip":"*.*.*.*"},
"install_agent":false,"is_auth_enabled":false,"is_enabled":true,"is_encrypted":false,
"is_synchable":false,"name":"win10","os_type":"Windows","priority":300,"use_ssl":false}
```

When I run the code, I am getting the following error
response Status: 403 Forbidden

Comment: Please provide information about API which you use

Comment: print the token and use the token with curl post with payload , there might be issue in token or payload. This will help you to narrow down the issue

Comment: Check the documentation for whatever API you're using. It's the API that is returning 403 forbidden. Most likely your credentials are wrong.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: My token is correct. when I use the same token with Postman it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

403 is Forbidden request - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403

I think you send wrong authToken

Check it more carefully.